# Set caps lock to esc on vmware workstation (ubuntu host and windows guest)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'd like to set caps lock to ESC in a Windows 7 machine running under vmware workstation 14 as guest with Ubuntu as the host OS. I'm following the [instructions here](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-E48970AB-0CDB-43C0-8FD6-15743849997C.html).

As a test (before setting caps lock to esc, or vice versa), I follow the instructions at the previous link to swap left-ctrl and caps lock by adding:

```
xkeymap.keycode.64 = "0x01d # X Caps_Lock -> VM left ctrl"
xkeymap.keycode.37 = "0x03a # X Control_L -> VM caps lock"
```

to the `.vmx` file. This doesn't swap the keys in the VM, even after rebooting the VM or restarting vmware workstation completely. I have also attempted adding the previous `xkeymap` lines to `~/.vmware/config` instead (as the link suggests). After restarting the VM, adding to `~/.vmware/config` also does not perform the swap.

Am I missing something?